# How to make a group of skeletons attack only specified scoreboard team?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

### Make skeletons shoot only at specified scoreboard team

---

I am trying to make a tower with skeletons. The skeletons in the tower will shoot at every player they see. The problem: I want only 1 group of skeletons (not `@e[type=Skeleton]`) to shoot at scoreboard team, called **team1**, for example. If we have a second team, called **team2**, for example, the skeletons **MUST NOT** attack them.

---

## Note

#### I am doing this on a 21 core server, which has anti clock - you can not run clock redstone!

Comment: You still can run clock redstone, you jsut put 2 hoppers aiming into each other and put one thing into them and place comparator to one of them. Bingo you have (maybe slow) clock that won't be affected by those silly plugins xD

Comment: @AntoineHejlík this is what I am currently using for clocks ;-) (there is even one more way), and the plugin isn't that stupid. It is part of a big project I develope and it reduces so much lag + physical server proccesses

Answer (score 1):

Based on the the information you've provided, you should be able to `/summon` the skeletons or use the `/entitiydata` command and add `Team:"(team2)"` to their attributes. The skeletons don't attack players on the same team as them, so they'd only attack people on team 1 (assuming you only have 2 teams, this should work fine).

Comment: What is the right command syntax  for 'entitydata' ? And the query selector must obtain a group of 5 skeletons, and if a sceleton got hurt by one from its team, it should ignore it.

Comment: I wouldn't use entitydata to add an entity to a team, I'd use `/scoreboard teams join <team> @e[type=skeleton,tag=<tag>]` to make all skeletons with the tag <tag> join <team>

Comment: Yeah, I tried the scoreboard command, but it didn't work for me. Said it only allowed players. The syntax for should be `/entitydata @e[type=skeleton,tag=<tag>] {TeamName:"team2"`}. If the scoreboard command works, my bad.